# Working with map function and vectors in R

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to understand the working of vectors with `purrr::map()` function. I have a vector `c("cat", "fish", "hamster")` and I want to convert it into the following output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "cat" "cat" "cat"

[[2]]
[1] "fish" "fish"

[[3]]
[1] "hamster"
```

Not sure about which `map()` function should I use and how to approach it. I find it as repetition of the first element thrice, 2 element twice and 3 third element just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need a package for this.  It would be faster with `rep` and `split`

```
v2 <- rep(v1, length(v1):1)
split(v2, v2)
#$cat
#[1] "cat" "cat" "cat"

#$fish
#[1] "fish" "fish"

#$hamster
#[1] "hamster"
```

---

Or use `imap`

```
library(purrr)
rev(imap(rev(v1), ~ rep(.x, .y)))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("cat", "fish", "hamster")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
x <- c("cat", "fish", "hamster")
map2(x, 3:1, rep)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `Map` + `replicate`

```
> Map(replicate, rev(seq_along(v)), v)
[[1]]
[1] "cat" "cat" "cat"

[[2]]
[1] "fish" "fish"

[[3]]
[1] "hamster"
```

Answer (score 1):

In base `R` you could use `mapply`:

```
v <- c("cat", "fish", "hamster")
mapply(rep, v, 3:1)
```

Or with `pmap`:

```
purrr::pmap(list(v, 3:1), rep)
```